# Make Pong on android using OpenGL-ES

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I am trying to make a simple pong game using opengl-es. I have checked out some of the tutorials/samples, but most of them are pre-dated to 2009.

I am familiar with game programming, and consider pong to be the hello-world!

Right now, I intend to make it using their supplied SDK (2.3), but eventually I want to make it in NDK, so I can port my other work to android.

Would anyone have a good reference for a starting point ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android [dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html). There are a few [samples](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/index.html) included in the documentation that cover the basics.  Probably enough for pong.

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ might be a better site for game specific questions.

Comment: I've already gone through the fundamentals guide and samples. However, I was trying to find something that can explain the bigger picture here.

Comment: So what specifically don't you understand? What have you tried, what isn't working?

Comment: Thanks Mayra. Moved my post to gamedev stackexchange. Should I close/delete this thread from here ?